# CocoaPods with React Native: `ld: library not found for -lReact`

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, react-native

I am integrating React Native with an existing iOS app. I have followed the [guide on integrating with an existing app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html).

After reading some other posts on the subject, I have tried:

- Setting the architecture in the Pod build to match the project
  settings in Xcode
- Adding / moving the Pod build above the project build in the Scheme

Is there anything else I may need to check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUCE and React Native - linker error "ld: library not found for -lReact"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792596/juce-and-react-native-linker-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lreact)

Answer (score 22):

Make sure you open xcworkspace file generated by pod install instead of your old xcodeproj file and then select the right scheme

Comment: I managed to figure it out, via another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792596/juce-and-react-native-linker-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lreact

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to change my deployment target to 11.0.  I had changed my Pods level to 11.0 but not the xcode setting.  Look in the Deployment Info section of your target General tab right next to the iPhone/IPad checkboxes.