# JUCE and React Native - linker error "ld: library not found for -lReact"

Tags: ios, cocoapods, react-native, juce

I'm getting this linker error using CocoaPods with React Native: 
`ld: library not found for -lReact`

I have followed the guide at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content

I am trying to integrate with an existing iOS project, which is a JUCE C++ project. JUCE generates the Xcode project file so I believe I need to use the Cocoapods method.

The steps I'm doing are:

- create or save iOS build from [Introjucer](http://www.juce.com/learn/introjucer) project
- run `npm install react-native` from root of project (alongside the `.jucer` file)
- create Podfile in `Builds/iOS` as per the guide (but with `../../node_modules` as the path)
- run `pod install`
- open workspace in Xcode
- adjust `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` to include `$(inherited)`
- build

An example project displaying this issue is at https://github.com/adamski/juce-native-navigation/tree/react-native-cocoapods

I think there is something going on with the Introjucer generated project, as I tried the whole process on a fresh new Xcode project and it builds fine.

I have also tried adding `libReact.a` to the 'Link Binary With Libraries' section but that does not seem to have helped.

Comment: Have you run `pod init`, created a podfile, ran `pod install` and the like?

Comment: Yes I have done all those things, following the guide linked above

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I've detailed the steps taken and an example project linked above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked for differences between the Introjucer generated project and the Xcode generated one.

One significant difference was the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` or "Per-configuration Build Products Path"

I copied over the setting from the Xcode generated project

`$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`

This allowed the linking to complete and gave a successful build :)

Comment: i am having the same problem but not with this package...im curious if you could describe where you copied the `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` to?

Comment: @ewizard in Binary Location

Comment: you mean just in `build settings -> per configuration Build Products Path`, if so mine already says that :(

Comment: actually i think it might be looking for a react pod instead of at my node_modules/react-native folder because I search for CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR and I see alot of ${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React in `React.xcconfig` file - should i change this to point to node_modules folder?

Comment: How can I find the Binary Location?
Can you guide me by using example?

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Project -> Your Target -> **Build Phases** -> Link Binary With Libraries and you might see some red entries there referring to the React library files here. Just remove those red entries and you should be good to go.

If there are no red entries, then just check that the list of libs in Link Binary With Libraries list has no items which you removed from React project using 'npm uninstall lib_name' command.

Answer (score 1):

Some steps may not be necessary and bring concerns of other, larger issues being hidden. Specifically:

```
adjust GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS to include $(inherited)
```

Namely, `pod install` scripts are supposed to do the `$(inherited)` magic for you.

Could a [configuration reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509278/218152) be of help?

Comment: Thanks, I followed the suggestions, remove configurations from the generated workspace (the original project had none set). I still get the linker error.

Comment: Also to add that step did get rid of the warning about `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project -> Your Target -> Build Settings -> Link Binary With Libraries and you might see some red entries there referring to the React library files here. Just remove those red entries and you should be good to go.

Comment: I got this error after I removed some third party libraries from my react-native project and did a clean rebuild in Xcode. Deleting these entries as well as the associated libraries solved the problem.